# Calculus II: Comparison Test for Divergence $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n+\sqrt{n}}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I have this math problem where I am a bit stuck. I have to show that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n+\sqrt{n}}$ diverges using the comparison test. I call this series $a_n$. I know that I have to find another series to compare it to. The other series ($b_n$) has to be less than or equal to $a_n$. I have to satisfy $a_n \geq b_n$ I tried to use $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}$ but $a_n$ will always be $< b_n$. Same with $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$

Answer (score 5):

Observe that: $\dfrac{1}{n+\sqrt{n}} > \dfrac{1}{2n}$

Comment: Wow, thank you so much!

Comment: (Except for $n = 1$, though of course that does not affect convergence.)